# Ignore Tokens on the Front of a Regular Expression in Powershell

Tags: powershell

Hi so I have read over regular expressions and all that but don't really fully understand it. Just looking for a little help here after a lot of searching on here and google.

I have an XML file that I am editing but for now let's pretend I'm doing just a single string. This works great except that I lose Connection Database="SQLEventLog" text in the replace. What kind of ignore token do I use here?

Here is my code

```
$passedString = '<Connection Database="SQLEventLog"       >Data 
Source=;Initial Catalog=Connector;Integrated Security=True</Connection>'

search($passedString)

function search ($string)
{
    $pattern = '*Data Source=*'

    if ($string -like '*Data Source=*')
    {
         Write-Warning 'found'
         $string = $string -replace '.*Data Source=*', 'Data 
         Source=localhost'
    }

    Write-Warning $string
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, a few things.  Best-practice for defining function parameters is to use the `Param()` clause.  Functions in PowerShell are not called with parenthesis, but are separated by spaces (e.g. `Function arg1 arg2 Arrayarg3,Arrayarg3`)

Additionally, the `-like` comparison operator does not use regex, it's a wildcard comparison.  I've updated your example to accomplish your goal.

```
Function Search
{
    Param($String)

    If ($String -like '*Data Source=*')
    {
         Write-Warning 'found'
         $string = $string -replace 'Data\sSource=', 'Data Source=localhost'
    }

    Write-Warning $string
}

$passedString = 'Data Source=;Initial Catalog=Connector;Integrated Security=True'

Search $passedString
```

Note: the `-replace` function DOES use regex for the first piece.

Comment: thanks that is much simpler than what I did. Tested it and it works.